# Shockwave Object in WinForm loads only once

Tags: c#, axshockwaveflash

I'm building a C# wrapper for a flash application that opens a socket with a  server. What troubles me is that everything works fine the first time i load the swf application in an axshockwaveflash object, but it stops working from the second time on, wether i open a second frame from the same session, or if i restart the application.

What i have to do to get it work again 1 time, is to delete all the temporary files in internet explorer. I don't have a clue about what's going on and the reasons of this behaviour. Has anybody else experienced it, and is there a solution?

PS: this doesn't happen if the flash application is loaded within the browser, even though I've just set the same Parameters and Variables

Comment: is this a web app with client side actionscript calling your c# code? Also what's your reason for opening a socket?

Comment: The flash application is a game I don't own, and no, the as inside it is not calling my c# code. I just wanted to be able to play it without having to use a browser, hence the wrapper

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your trying to use Adobe Flash as your interface; then pass certain variables back into C#.

An example would be this:

In Flash; create a button...
Actionscript:

```
 on (press) {
    fscommand("Yo","dude");
}
```

Then Visual Studio you just need to add the COM object reference: **Shockwave Flash Object**

Then set the embed to true;

Then inside Visual Studio you should be able to go to Properties; find fscommand.  The fscommand will allow you to physically connect the value from the Flash movie.

```
AxShockwaveFlashObjects._IShockwaveFlashEvents_FSCommandEvent
```

That collects; then just use **e.command** and **e.arg** for example to have the collected item do something.

Then add this to the EventHandler;

```
lbl_Result.Text="The "+e.args.ToString()+" "+e.command.ToString()+" was clicked";
```

And boom it's transmitting it's data from Flash into Visual Studio. No need for any crazy difficult sockets.

On a side note; if you have Flash inside Visual Studio the key is to ensure it's **"embed is set to true."** That will hold all the path references within the Flash Object; to avoid any miscalling to incorrect paths.

I'm not sure if that is the answer your seeking; or answers your question.  But without more details on your goal / error.  I can't assist you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not what I am trying to do

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish; or trying to do I should say?